# Insert an element into a PostgreSQL array without overwriting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to insert some data to array column in postgres.

```
sample_model = MyModel.create
100.times do
  sample_model.array.push [Time.now.to_i, 1234]
  sample_model.save  
end
```

This takes 0.5 seconds to complete and is very inefficient. This code overwrites the array every time. The same code using mongoDB and mongoid takes about 0.08 seconds to complete.

```
sample_model = MyMongoidModel.create
100.times do
  sample_model.push(array: [[Time.now.to_i, 1234]]) 
end
```

Is there any way to insert an element to postgres array column like mongo does? I'll even consider any pure SQL solutions.

Comment: In SQL you simply do `array_column || 1234` to append a value to the end of the array. I don't know anything about Rails but it looks terribly inefficient to me to save the model _inside_ the loop (which you don't do for Mongo btw). I would expect that it is sufficient to save the model **once** after the loop

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what ruby code should I write to do it? thx. Its just a sample code. In real life I need to append an element to an array of 1000 elements, so its not really efficient to overwrite it.

Comment: Internally PostgreSQL *can't* update arrays in-place. They are *always* copied to a new row because of MVCC requirements. If you're updating fields heavily, use a relational design with a join table, not an array. You can update the array in SQL by splitting and concatenating it, but you're still writing a new row with a new array, even it *looks* like an update.

Comment: @CraigRinger I tried to do it with join table and I got the same task as above done in 0.3 - 0.4 seconds. Not really fast.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Solution:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :time_entries, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :my_model
end

class TimeEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_model, inverse_of :time_entries
  validates_presence_of: time
end

100.times {MyModel.last.time_entries.create(time: Time.now)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever read this: https://www.coffeepowered.net/2009/01/23/mass-inserting-data-in-rails-without-killing-your-performance/

I think that *Option 3 - A single mass insert* is what you're looking for.

Comment: This is not my case. The code above is just a sample. I need to insert a new element to an array which already has 1000 elements and then save the object.